# WCF Test Client : Failed to add a service. Service metadata may not be accessible. Make sure your service is running and exposing metadata

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, exception, microsoft-sync-framework

I am currently trying to get the sync framework sample working: [sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Database-SyncSQL-Server-e97d1208)

The solution compiles with out any error or warning.

But when I hit F5 the WCF Test Client launches and throws the following error.

> Local\Temp\Test Client
>   Projects\10.0\5b6aab8a-6629-4a12-87c2-e9e75ba9c1e4\Client.cs(379,13) :
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'schema' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Below is the code from `Client.cs` that the above error is referencing

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("svcutil", "4.0.30319.1")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.Synchronization")]
public partial class SyncIdFormatGroup
{
    private schema schemaField;
    private System.Xml.XmlElement anyField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema", Order=0)]
    public schema schema
    {
        get { return this.schemaField; }
        set { this.schemaField = value; }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAnyElementAttribute(Order=1)]
    public System.Xml.XmlElement Any
    {
        get { return this.anyField; }
        set { this.anyField = value; }
    }
}
```

It would be great if some one could help me with the problem.

Comment: Have you created a class called schema? I think it is complaining that schema is a keyword maybe?

Comment: Can you show the code of schema class , is it tagedd with     [DataContract] attribute and its member with    [DataMember] attribute?

Comment: @stuartmclark  I do not have any class called schema. The class I am referring to is created by WCTTestClient

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution Ok, after spending lot of time I cracked it. For some reason if I run the sample as console app it just works fine. But the moment I use WCFTestClient I was getting errors. If I remove the `[ServiceKnownType(typeof(SyncIdFormatGroup))]` from the contract it works in WCFTestClient. Hope that helps someone.

Comment: Congrats on the solution.  When you are able, please make sure to mark your answer as 'accepted' so that others might learn from your success.  Cheers~

Comment: Sorry guys, completely lost track. Have Marked the answer

Answer (score 2):

Have you enabled a mex (metadata exchange) endpoint in your service?

```
<endpoint 
      address="mex" 
      binding="mexHttpBinding" 
      contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the note at the end of the page:
Note: If you use Visual Studio 2010 to compile these samples, you will first need to remove references to the Sync Framework assemblies and then re-add the assembly references to the projects. Otherwise, you will see "type or namespace name could not be found" compilation errors.
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Database-Sync-SQL-Server-7e88adab#content
or
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Database-SyncSQL-Server-e97d1208

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow - good first answer. One way of improving your answer would be to clarify which "page" you;re referring to ...