# WCF Service to talk to another WCF Service

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, visual-studio

I created a new Test WCF Application.  It runs fine with the Simple GetData method with the WCF Test Client when I run the solution in Visual Studio.  However I now want to add a Service Reference to an external WCF Service so that I can talk to it from this Web Service.  So the interface for me Service1 now looks like:

```
public interface IService1 : MyExternalService
```

Then on my service class where I have the simple GetData I can hit Implement Interfaces and I see all the methods for the External Web Service created:

```
     public class Service1 : IService1
        {
            public string GetData(int value)
            {
                return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
            }

            public string ExternalMethod1(string a, string b)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

//etc
```

However if I try to run this with the WCF Test Client - I get the following error message - `Failed to add a service. Service metadata may not be accessible. Make sure your service is running and exposing metadata.`

After I included the External Service Ref it updated my web.config to as below (note some actual urls scrubbed)

```
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IExternalService">
          <security>
            <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IExternalService1">
          <security>
            <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" negotiateServiceCredential="false"
              algorithmSuite="Basic128" establishSecurityContext="false" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://service.com/ExternalService/ExternalService.svc"
        binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IExternalService"
        contract="ExternalService.IExternalService" name="WSHttpBinding_IExternalService">
        <identity>
          <dns value="service.com" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
      <endpoint address="http://service.com/ExternalService/ExternalService.svc/Java"
        binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IExternalService1"
        contract="ExternalService.IExternalService" name="WSHttpBinding_IExternalService1">
        <identity>
          <dns value="service.com" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a metadata exchange endpoint to the first service

```
<services>
   <service name="MyService.MyService" behaviorConfiguration="metadataBehavior">
      <endpoint 
          address="http://localhost/MyService.svc" 
          binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="jsonpBinding" 
          behaviorConfiguration="MyService.MyService"
          contract="MyService.IMyService"/>
      <endpoint 
          address="mex" 
          binding="mexHttpBinding" 
          contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
   </service>
</services>
```

This thread seems to discuss the same issue [WCF Test Client : Failed to add a service. Service metadata may not be accessible. Make sure your service is running and exposing metadata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7889115/wcf-test-client-failed-to-add-a-service-service-metadata-may-not-be-accessibl)

Comment: In what section of the web config would that be?

Comment: <system.ServiceModel>
   <services>
    ...
  </services>
</system.ServiceModel> You should already have this section in the first service

Comment: Can you check whether you have mapped the correct service class and code behind in the .svc file. You can Right click the Service*.svc file then select 'View Mark Up' to view the mapping.

Comment: Can you also check this http://www.danderson.me/posts/cannot-obtain-metadata-from-wcf-service-when-using-microsoft-wcf-test-client/